# Writing custom parser using ANTLR4, C# and VS2017

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to parse files that have a format as below. What I'd like to be able to do is create a few vars and an array of structs to contain information about the file. For example there could be (pseudocode) `int atomNumber = 27` and then `string struct[0].element = C` & `float struct[0].x = 0.6877350`. I would need a parser/script that allows me to get that information out of the file. I'm trying to do this with ANTLR/custom parser instead of Regex because some of these files get big; I was doing this in Unity and Regex was slow due to its effect on Unity's garbage collection. However I'm new to using ANTLR so I'm struggling to get this to work.

Here is an example of the file structure:

```
27
 comment 
C 0.6877350 0.0715370 -1.2710340
C 0.0387890 -0.2132770 2.4629140
C 2.9026270 0.7676750 -0.4325690
C 1.9897370 0.2682320 -1.4699130
H 3.8932221 0.3135170 -0.4057700
H 2.3979900 0.0407470 -2.4529259
H 0.0607820 -1.2602330 2.1661179
H 0.1969520 0.2155350 -0.3100010
O -0.1311780 -0.2708320 -2.3204310
C -1.0381711 -1.2940150 -2.2029400
O -1.8197130 -1.4577920 -3.0971811
C -0.9588580 -2.1451390 -0.9617850
H 0.0764330 -2.4116330 -0.7270430
H -1.5478179 -3.0458710 -1.1361990
H -1.3813020 -1.6050299 -0.1051530
C 1.0799000 0.3532050 3.0701120
H 1.9819210 -0.2100150 3.2911880
H 1.0789630 1.4006370 3.3635521
C 2.6065600 1.7304400 0.4415480
H 3.3160350 2.0450499 1.2023780
H 1.6531780 2.2537251 0.4046360
C -1.2067200 0.5084640 2.0837281
C -1.4050720 1.9360650 2.5400000
H -0.6525800 2.5874960 2.0799990
H -2.3981910 2.2678981 2.2341671
H -1.3007090 2.0248840 3.6260951
O -2.0373070 -0.0501320 1.3878731
27
 comment 
C 0.6835910 0.0801290 -1.2651600
C 0.0385760 -0.2142480 2.4595370
C 2.9039860 0.7584860 -0.4261270
C 1.9882360 0.2606780 -1.4617670
H 3.8887999 0.2924340 -0.3916030
H 2.3965650 0.0209800 -2.4418731
H 0.0600150 -1.2637050 2.1717429
H 0.1919770 0.2365210 -0.3064940
O -0.1368310 -0.2607420 -2.3141041
C -1.0378500 -1.2895941 -2.1994519
O -1.8194150 -1.4546410 -3.0934210
C -0.9520160 -2.1443820 -0.9613080
H 0.0850850 -2.4055369 -0.7287190
H -1.5361210 -3.0478990 -1.1376450
H -1.3763330 -1.6092030 -0.1024920
C 1.0823750 0.3586390 3.0560379
H 1.9862601 -0.2015870 3.2770901
H 1.0818750 1.4086040 3.3402641
C 2.6171989 1.7337860 0.4371280
H 3.3282030 2.0474880 1.1969039
H 1.6705470 2.2685010 0.3915880
C -1.2096530 0.5029830 2.0807769
C -1.4067100 1.9345620 2.5251229
H -0.6585890 2.5824180 2.0530601
H -2.4025259 2.2620981 2.2234540
H -1.2943890 2.0340610 3.6094720
O -2.0432911 -0.0622970 1.3940520
27
 comment 
C 0.6785940 0.0895900 -1.2592160
C 0.0387820 -0.2150840 2.4559050
C 2.9046619 0.7487670 -0.4192210
C 1.9859340 0.2525420 -1.4530050
H 3.8832800 0.2704900 -0.3765630
H 2.3943379 -0.0007300 -2.4296930
H 0.0600560 -1.2667160 2.1762300
H 0.1859720 0.2598610 -0.3034400
O -0.1432220 -0.2500770 -2.3077281
C -1.0374310 -1.2852740 -2.1962149
O -1.8187211 -1.4521340 -3.0900691
C -0.9445940 -2.1436851 -0.9611460
H 0.0943740 -2.3994770 -0.7311130
H -1.5238889 -3.0499580 -1.1391890
H -1.3703721 -1.6133870 -0.1000140
C 1.0848000 0.3637940 3.0426750
H 1.9905159 -0.1934890 3.2636609
H 1.0843771 1.4159710 3.3185790
C 2.6278651 1.7370080 0.4325060
H 3.3405459 2.0497701 1.1910950
H 1.6883790 2.2834129 0.3780430
C -1.2120970 0.4977380 2.0776091
C -1.4083090 1.9328350 2.5109861
H -0.6641670 2.5774081 2.0282159
H -2.4065051 2.2563839 2.2129040
H -1.2890840 2.0420361 3.5936451
O -2.0483761 -0.0737650 1.3993220
```

So basically it's going to have

{integer}

{comment to throw away}

{integer number of lines with 4 columns, CHAR FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT}

(repeat per number of frames but with different floats on the lines)

I've attempted to write an ANTLR4 grammar file to parse this:

```
grammar XYZ;
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

file                : header comment line+ EOF;
line                : ELEMENT FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT NEWLINE;
header              : INT NEWLINE;
comment             : WORD+ NEWLINE;
/*
 * Lexer Rules
*/

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment NUMBER     : [0-9]+ ;
INT                 : NUMBER ;
FLOAT               : '-'? NUMBER '.' NUMBER ;
WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE)+ ;
ELEMENT             : 'A' .. 'Z' ;
WHITESPACE          : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE             : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;
```

I generate the scripts in CMD using the command `java -jar antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar -Dlanguage=CSharp XYZ.g4`

Then finally in main I have the following code snippet to run the program (input is the above text)

```
    AntlrInputStream istream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
    XYZLexer lexer = new XYZLexer(istream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    XYZParser parser = new XYZParser(tokens);
    XYZParser.LineContext lineContext = parser.line();

    Console.WriteLine(lineContext.GetText());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

What I get is a terminal window that says `line 1:0 mismatched input '27' expecting ELEMENT` as well as returning the text in input.

using

```
    XYZParser.FileContext fileContext = parser.file();
    Console.WriteLine(fileContext.GetText());
```

instead gives me `line 3:0 mismatched input 'C' expecting ELEMENT`

How am I able to go from this to getting rid of the error and using the ANTLR runtime to get the data?

ANS:

Changing the grammar file to prevent overlap between WORD and ELEMENT

```
grammar XYZ;
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

file                : frame+ EOF;
frame               : header comment line+;
line                : ELEMENT FLOAT FLOAT FLOAT NEWLINE;
header              : INT NEWLINE;
comment             : (ELEMENT | WORD+) NEWLINE;
/*
 * Lexer Rules
*/

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment NUMBER     : [0-9]+ ;
INT                 : NUMBER ;
FLOAT               : '-'? NUMBER '.' NUMBER ;
ELEMENT             : 'A' .. 'Z' ;
WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE)+ ;
WHITESPACE          : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip ;
NEWLINE             : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;
```

changing the script to

```
AntlrInputStream istream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
XYZLexer lexer = new XYZLexer(istream);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
XYZParser parser = new XYZParser(tokens);
XYZParser.FileContext fileContext = parser.line();

Console.WriteLine(fileContext.GetText());
Console.ReadLine();
```

for getting everything

for just seeing one value, an example is

```
    AntlrInputStream istream = new AntlrInputStream(input);
    XYZLexer lexer = new XYZLexer(istream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    XYZParser parser = new XYZParser(tokens);

    XYZParser.FileContext fileContext = parser.file();
    XYZParser.FrameContext frameContext = fileContext.frame()[0];
    XYZParser.LineContext lineContext = frameContext.line()[0];

    IParseTree tree = lineContext.FLOAT()[0];
    Console.WriteLine(tree.GetText());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> XYZParser.LineContext lineContext = parser.line();
> ```

You're trying to apply the rule `line`, which expects an `ELEMENT` at the beginning, but your input starts with the number 27, which is an `INT`, not an `ELEMENT`. You should apply the rule `file` instead, which does expect an `INT` at the beginning.

Comment: That gives me a different error: `line 3:0 mismatched input 'C' expecting ELEMENT`

Comment: @Chylomicron Ah, that's because your `WORD` and `ELEMENT` rules overlap (and `WORD` comes first).

Comment: Ohh I see. I didn't realize the order mattered in ANTLR. I switched WORD and ELEMENT and also added a frame parser (`file    : frame+ EOF;
frame    : header comment line+;`) and that didn't produce any errors. Thanks! :)

Comment: How would I go about just getting a single value now? Like if I wanted to access for example the first frame, second atom y coordinate?

Comment: @Chylomicron Note that single upper-case characters are now always `ELEMENT`s, so they're no longer allowed in comments unless you amend the comment rule to allow `ELEMENT`s as well as `WORD`s.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I changed it to `comment    : (ELEMENT | WORD+) NEWLINE;` and tested with a frame comment as just "C" and it didn't produce errors

Comment: oh I figured out how to get the specific values. I think I'm starting to get the basics of how ANTLR works now. Thanks a bunch for the help!